# How do you remove json keys from a list in python?

Tags: python, json

I have some json that I have converted to a list in Python like this:

```
jsonText = '[{"stationID":"ABCD1234","obsTimeUtc":"2021-05-04T11:53:04Z","obsTimeLocal":"2021-05-04 21:53:04","neighborhood":"HelloWorld","softwareType":"SoftwareHelloWorld","country":"Hello","solarRadiation":0.0,"lon":1234.1234,"realtimeFrequency":null,"epoch":12345678,"lat":1234.1234,"uv":0.0,"winddir":1234,"humidity":1234,"qcStatus":1,"imperial":{"temp":57,"heatIndex":57,"dewpt":56,"windChill":57,"windSpeed":0,"windGust":0,"pressure":29.95,"precipRate":0.07,"precipTotal":0.21,"elev":56}}]'
listText = js.loads(jsonText)
print('--NEW FORMAT--')
print(listText)
```

Which returns this list:

```
[{'stationID': 'ABCD1234', 'obsTimeUtc': '2021-05-04T11:53:04Z', 'obsTimeLocal': '2021-05-04 21:53:04', 'neighborhood': 'HelloWorld', 'softwareType': 'SoftwareHelloWorld', 'country': 'Hello', 'solarRadiation': 0.0, 'lon': 1234.1234, 'realtimeFrequency': None, 'epoch': 12345678, 'lat': 1234.1234, 'uv': 0.0, 'winddir': 1234, 'humidity': 1234, 'qcStatus': 1, 'imperial': {'temp': 57, 'heatIndex': 57, 'dewpt': 56, 'windChill': 57, 'windSpeed': 0, 'windGust': 0, 'pressure': 29.95, 'precipRate': 0.07, 'precipTotal': 0.21, 'elev': 56}}]
```

However I don't want the keys in the list (stationID:. obsTimeUtc: etc.), only the values so that it would look more like this:

```
[["ABCD1234","2021-05-04T11:53:04Z","2021-05-04 21:53:04","HelloWorld","SoftwareHelloWorld","Hello",0.0,1234.1234,"null",12345678,1234.1234,0.0,1234,1234,1,57,57,56,57,0,0,29.95,0.07,0.21,56]]
```

How do I remove the "keys" in the list and just keep the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with a list comprehension. This will handle the case when there are multiple dicts in the list structure:

```
data = [list(d.values()) for d in listText]
```

To handle recursive dicts I would use a generator:

```
def flatten(listText):
    def _flatten(item):
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            for value in item.values():
                yield from _flatten(value)
        else:
            yield item

    return [list(_flatten(d)) for d in listText]
```

Comment: The problem is that if some value is also a dict, this approach won´t work. You need a recursive solution, as I did in my answer.

Comment: Based on the result example given by the OP, the solution definitely requieres handling nested dicts

Comment: This works almost perfectly however it still returns the list with keys after from 'imperial:'- I believe this is because it is nested. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: A one dimensional list is all that needs to be returned :)

Comment: @BenHarvey Ah I missed that. Updated.

Comment: Ah I just realized that in the actual json there is a {"observations": at the beginning of the string. So when your code is run it just returns [['observations']]. How would this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

`list(listText[0].values())` will make a list of the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
def listFromDict(d):
    resultList = []
    for k in d.keys():
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            resultList.extend(listFromDict(d[k]))
        else:
            resultList.append(d[k])
        
    return resultList

result = []
for e in listText:
    result.append(listFromDict(e))

print(result)
```

Comment: In this case is "d" a dictionary or would it be the listText from my original code

Comment: d is just a variable in the listFromDict function. Your listText is used below in the code

Comment: I just realized that my formatting was wrong, now it is indented properly